# Clique left click casting like vuhdo

Tags: world-of-warcraft

For many years I have used the vuhdo addon to help me while healing.

Recently I have abandoned it and decided to use the default unit frames in conjunction with an addon called clique.

I use the following custom macro to cast a heal

```
/cast [target=mouseover, exists, help,nodead] Shadow Mend
/cast Shadow Mend
```

What would I need to do  to allow me to cast Shadow mend (or any other spell) when left clicking on a default unit frame but also to keep the behaviour of targeting when clicking on a player character.

Answer (score 1):

In Clique, use the following macro:

```
/tar [@mouseover]
/cast [@mouseover] Shadow Mend
```

This will select the target you're aiming at (default left mouse button behavior) and cast the spell (Shadow Mend in this case) on him.

You can replace `/cast [@mouseover] Shadow Mend` with whatever macro you already have for that.